# is it possible to run multiple version of gimp without a Vm

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, gimp

I am having problems with my tablet on gimp 2.8 and unable to use in this version. when I use 2.6 it works perfectly fine. I'm currently using gimp 2.8 a uni and was wondering if there was a way to install both versions without a virtual machine. i would not be able to run a VM on pc

Comment: What host and guest OS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can run both versions of gimp, by default the gimp installer installs gimp in different directories for different version. or you can do this by customizing the setup and installing for example Gimp 2.6 in C:\Program Files\Gimp-2.6\ and the Gimp 2.8 in C:\Program Files\Gimp-2.8\

That way you will have both versions installed and you can use them but not at once means you need to close one version first before launching the second version.

Please let us know it this helps you...

Comment: You can use both at once if you tell new instance to open as such (otherwise they tell the running instance to load whatever image they have been given as a parameter, and exit early). 
You can use the command-line parameter -n to make sure that you get a new instance of GIMP.

Comment: when trying to install gimp 2.8.18 it doesn't have a way to change directory and when i install gimp 2.6 in a different directory it over write the gimp 2.8.18 regardless of directory